# Change HTML item_status Class in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i have HTML below:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" class="product-data" rules="all"><tbody>
<tr><td class="item_price">$ 3.99</td> </tr>
<tr class="" style="color: #aaaaaa; text-decoration: line-through;"><td class="item_beforeprice">$ 39.95</td></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr class="hidden"><td class="item_status">Sold</td></tr>
<tr><td></table>
```

And then if my page was loaded and see the **Sold** text i want to change the:

```
<td class="item_status">Sold</td>
```

To:

```
<td class="item_status sold-status">Sold</td>
```

and if the code is:

```
<td class="item_status">Offer</td>
```

Change to:

```
<td class="item_status offer-status">Offer</td>
```

Thank you before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add class to your .item-status, if you use jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('.item_status').addClass('sold-status');
})
```

With pure javascript:

```
document.querySelector('.item_status').classList.add('sold-status');
```

Update: Detect sold text
With jQuery:

```
$('.product-data td').each(function () {
   if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() == 'sold') {
        $(this).addClass('sold-status');
   }
})
```

With pure Javascript

```
var td = document.querySelectorAll('.product-data td');
td.forEach(function(element) {
   if (element.innerText.toLowerCase() === 'sold') {
       element.classList.add('sold-status');
   }
})
```

Comment: how about if javascript find the Sold text and then automaticaly change the class?

Comment: Hope, it will help you

Comment: thank you its work using pure javascript, but how to work without detecting the product-data class? i mean just detect the sold text

Comment: i solve it with:
`var td = document.querySelectorAll('td');
td.forEach(function(element) {
   if (element.innerText.toLowerCase() === 'sold') {
       element.classList.add('sold-status');
   }
})`

thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var itemStatus = document.querySelector('.item_status');

   // with className method
    itemStatus.className += ' sold-status';

   // with classList
   itemStatus.classList.add('sold-status');
});
```

Use the method ( classList or className ) best convenient for you

Answer (score 0):

This will run after the page is loaded.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var item = document.getElementsByClassName("item_status");
    item.className += 'sold-status';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work!

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('item_status').className = 'item_status sold- status';
};
```

Or in jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('.item_status').addClass('item_status sold- status');
});
```

Comment: how about if javascript find the Sold text and then automaticaly change the class?

Comment: Yes, you can, By comparing the element's innerHTML with sold and then executing the above code would get the result you need.@Almaftuchin

Comment: yes i understand, but i have more status for example:
Sold, Offers, and Deal, if i use this, all class will replace all, anyway thank you for your reply